# Distinguish between A* and A in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, countif

I’m creating a spreadsheet to be used in schools that use various countifs, subtotals etc to look up data. A big problem I have is that I need to distinguish and count separately students on an A* (A star) and those on an A. At the moment they are counting both as one - is there anyway around this?
Every spreadsheet used will express the A* in that way so for usability I am keen for it to be presented in that way rather than just change it to a different letter. Many thanks

Comment: How are you currently finding your A's?

Comment: If I start a blank excel page I can type A in a cell or A* in a cell. If I right click and click format I see it listed as "General"

Comment: The question was which operation doesn't distinguish between the two.

Comment: Escape the star

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10="A*"))
```

[image]

The formula in **C1** is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10="A"))
```

Which, as you see, returns a *3*.

**NOTE:**

If we use:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"A*")
```

we would get an *8*, because `COUNTF()` treats the star as a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

The EXACT function will give you the case sensitivity, use this formula

=SUMPRODUCT(EXACT(A1:A100,"A")*1)

=SUMPRODUCT(EXACT(A1:A100,"A*")*1)

Comment: I've worked this in. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

`COUNTIF()` and `COUNTIFS()` do support wildcards. The asterisk happens to be a wildcard character which means "zero or more characters (of any type)". Therefor you get these unwanted results. But keep in mind; you can always escape the special meaning of a wildcard using a tilde. Therefor you can use:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,"A~*")
```

[image]

Comment: So simple! Thank you